# gitflow hot fix branch vs long lived release branch

Tags: git, release, git-flow, branching-strategy

I've been looking at the gitflow workflow a bit http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/, and it makes sense and is very similar to what I've done in the past. I've done things a little differently when it comes to releasing and hot fixing and wanted to ask about the advantage or disadvantage of they way gitflow branches vs how I've proposed.

Typically when I create a release branch, say for release 1.0.0, I'll name the release branch release-1.0.x, not release-1.0.0. Once I create the branch (but before the code is released), the version will be 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT for any last minute fixes. When I release, I create release version of 1.0.0, tag it and merger to master. Now rather than deleting the release branch, I increment the version to 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT. This effectively becomes a long-lived hot fix branch for the release 1.0.x series. If I find a bug in production, I'll fix it on this branch, cut a 1.0.1 release version and increment the version to 1.0.2-SNAPSHOT, and so on.

The downside is that release branch exists for as long as this release is the current release. The upside is that I don't need to create new hot fix branches if there's a bug, and the branch already exists.

So my question is am I missing any major issues here by not having the hot fix branches and doing it this way?

Comment: I am also looking for opinions around this strategy. We're into Android app development and I keep release branch open as long as I don't create another release branch. No need of hotfix branches. It's very convenient.

Answer (score 1):

We have adopted the nvie model at work and it works very well.

The hotfix is only used for minor patches to the released software - and will have a very short lifetime before they are merged to master and deleted. Meanwhile the develop branch is used for work towards major improvements.

The (minor) advantage I see to the nvie model is the short livespan of hotfix branches. In a team of people, I can see the advantage of having a hotfix branch ready for them to use if needed.

Comment: I can see the advantage of keeping branches short lives. It prevents the painful merges. Even though we're merging immediately after we make the fixes on the release branch, there may not really be a reason to keep it around and we could just use hotfix branches.